# Fermi liquid/gas and Goldstones

Tags: symmetry-breaking, fermi-liquids

Often, we say that the low-energy excitations of a quantum system that spontaneously breaks certain symmetries is described by Goldstone bosons. It is also well-known that Fermi liquids and gases are described by quasiparticle modes as low frequency excitations of the Fermi surface.

**Question** Is there any sense in which the quasiparticles describing the low-energy dynamics of Fermi liquids and gases can be understood as Goldstones (possibly related to the spontaneous symmetry breaking of boosts)?

Comment: Do you have a specific spontaneously-symmetry breaking Fermi liquid in mind?

Comment: At a minimum. Fermi liquids must break Lorentz boost symmetry (or in the non-relativistic approximation, Galilean boost symmetry)... not sure if it breaks any others.

Comment: why do Fermi liquids need to break Lorentz boost symmetry?

Comment: because these is a preferred rest-frame, namely the rest frame of the fermi liquid. In other words, think about a fermi liquid at rest vs one that is boosted to some non-zero velocity... they will be in different states, i.e. boosts are spontaneously broken.